# Создание обработчика события из MainWindow.cs на Page1.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

В чем дело?, я хочу добавить обработчик события из `MainWindow.xaml.cs` на `Page1.xaml`, во `Page1.xaml` есть элемент `testButton`, в `MainWindow.xaml` есть `btn`, при нажатие на которую выполняется код:

`new Page1().TestButton.Click += (s, e) => SendMsg();`

Метод `SendMsg` просто выводит messagebox с сообщением hello.

Код без ошибок, но почему то вообще не выполняется, никаких исключений нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81911/discussion-on-question-by-mairwunnx-----mainwindow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код

```
new Page1().TestButton.Click += (s, e) => SendMsg();
```

Создает страницу в памяти компьютера но никогда её не отображает. Вот этот код

```
frame1.Source = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Отображает **другую** страницу, никак не связанную с первой. Если вам нужно создать страницу, настроить её как вам удобно и отобразить, вы можете это сделать следующим образом

```
var page = new Page1(); // создаем страницу и сохраняем её в переменную
page.TestButton.Click += (s, e) => SendMsg(); // делаем со страницей что хотим
frame1.Content= page; // отображаем страницу
```

Comment: другое дело, спасибо!